Sending an event Meta's Conversion API into my Wordpress website with GravityForms
I am new to WordPress development. I have a form on my website powered by GravityForms and it collects full name, address (powered by google), phone and email. I created a PHP script that helps me send a lead event through the server using Meta's Conversion API. Trying to integrate the code in my functions.php file breaks the website and gives critical error. I can't pinpoint where the problem lies exactly.
The code I came up with looks like this:
<?php
// Adding the hook to Gravity Forms submission
add_action('gform_after_submission', 'handle_form_submission', 10, 2);

function handle_form_submission($entry, $form)
{
    // Setup configuration variables
    $pixel_id = 'example-pixel-id';
    $access_token = 'example-access-token';

    // Collect data from the form entry using the label-based function
    $userData = collectFormDataByLabel($entry, $form);

    // Prepare the data payload
    $payload = preparePayload($userData);

    // Send the data to Facebook Conversion API
    $response = sendToFacebookAPI($pixel_id, $access_token, $payload);

    // Optionally log the response for debugging
    error_log('Facebook API Response: ' . $response);
}

function findFieldByLabel($form, $label)
{
    foreach ($form['fields'] as $field) {
        if (strcasecmp($field->label, $label) == 0) {
            return $field->id;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

function collectFormDataByLabel($entry, $form)
{
    $labels = [
        'Full Name' => 'full_name',
        'Property Address' => 'address',
        'Phone' => 'phone',
        'Email' => 'email'
    ];

    $userData = [];

    foreach ($labels as $label => $key) {
        $field_id = findFieldByLabel($form, $label);
        if ($field_id) {
            $userData[$key] = rgar($entry, (string)$field_id);
        }
    }

    return $userData;
}


function preparePayload($userData)
{
    $event_id = uniqid('evt_', true);
    $event_source_url = "https://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]";

    return [
        'data' => [
            [
                'event_name' => 'Lead',
                'event_time' => time(),
                'event_source_url' => $event_source_url,
                'event_id' => $event_id,
                'user_data' => [
                    'em' => hash('sha256', $userData['email']),
                    'ph' => hash('sha256', $userData['phone']),
                    'fn' => hash('sha256', explode(' ', $userData['full_name'])[0]),
                    'ln' => hash('sha256', explode(' ', $userData['full_name'])[1] ?? ''),
                    'st' => hash('sha256', $userData['address']),
                ],
                'action_source' => 'website',
            ],
        ],
    ];
}

function sendToFacebookAPI($pixel_id, $access_token, $payload)
{
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://graph.facebook.com/v19.0/$pixel_id/events?access_token=$access_token");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($payload));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/json'));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

    $response = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);

    return $response;
}

Is there anyone with experience willing to help me figure what's the problem?

Start by enabling WP debug mode, and see what errors that actually reports.

Thanks! I did and found out it was a syntax generated by me pasting the snippet with the '` which was unnecessary.
